# Android x86 in VirtualBox: “FATAL: NO BOOTABLE MEDIUM FOUND. SYSTEM HALTED” directly after installation

Tags: android-x86, virtualbox

“FATAL: NO BOOTABLE MEDIUM FOUND. SYSTEM HALTED” appears on Android x86 6.0 rc3, **but not on Linux Mint or Windows XP,** immediately after installation.

The boot order is correct.
What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That was likely a flaw in Android x86 Marshmallow, which has already been patched in Android x86 Nougat, according to my tests.